# How to run a bash file, MAC OS, without “./”?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash file `mytest.sh` that should be distributed for another users.

In a regular scenario we should be able to run that script trough `./mytest.sh` command when inside the same folder the file is located.

I want them to be allowed to run the alias `runtest` anywhere in theirs machine in order to run that script.

how to do that?

Comment: What does 'in MAC" mean?

Comment: How does "runtest" relate to "mytest.sh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install mytest.sh in some `bin` directory (check them using `echo $PATH`). Then cd into that directory and

```
sudo ln -s mytest.sh runtest
```

Now `runtest` command works from everywhere.

Comment: Aliases are a really poor solution here. Noninteractive shells ignore them by default, so they can't be used by scripts without explicit effort. (Also, `/etc/profile` is run by *login* shells, as opposed to non-login interactive shells -- so you can define a function in `/etc/profile` and export it, and that'll work in all instances of bash, but an alias there will only be honored by a user's login shells and not non-login shells it spawns).

Comment: Thanks, I don't like them, either. Removed from answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the folder that contains the script to your PATH.

```
export PATH+=":/ROUTE/TO/FOLDER/SCRIPT"
```

Then, you can execute the script on your terminal without the "./".

If you want to do this with all the users, you can add to the "/etc/environment" file.